# How to store high precision floats in a binary file, Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, floating-point-precision

In Python 2.7,I need to record high precision floats (such as np.float64 from numpy or Decimal from decimal module) to a binary file and later read it back. How could I do it? I would like to store only bit image of a high precision float, without any overhead. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `struct` module can handle 64 bit floats. Decimals are another matter - the binary representation is a string of digits. Probably not what you want. You could covert it to BCD to halve the amount of storage.

Answer (score 0):

Without further details, I'd just store a [compressed](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) [pickle'd](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) representation of the data. It will record data and read it back exactly as it was and will not "waste" bits.